# Best practice to migrate data from a release to the next

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-migration

I was wondering if there is a best practice or a common pattern to migrate the live data from a live database of an old release to a new database of a newer release.

Last time i wrote lots of SQL scripts and ran them manually, now i am thinking about using SSIS but still i have to create a data flow task for every table in my database,taking in consideration schema changes!

Are there any better solutions?

Edit : i am using MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: SSIS is not the right tool for this job in my opinion.  Consider SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx or RedGate tools http://www.red-gate.com/products.  Regardless of the toolset, source control and sound development processes are the key.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK The best approach is maintaining during development time a chronological ordered list of files (for example by naming the files with the current timestamp) where each file contains the schema alternation scripts for that certain point in time.

This way, when you wish to migrate the old release DB to the new one, you first run all of those scripts by their chronological order and nothing should break. Only then you should seed the DB with updated data, if such exists.

Most modern BE frameworks offer some kind of migration handling of such. for example, PHP Laravel framework offers migrations mechanism for exactly this. check it out [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations).